# Issue Blank pages between printing stickers HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, printing

I have this issue with printing sticker labels to a restaurant menu orders I am using TSC DA210 Printer and the sticker label size is 102mm x 24mm.

The problem is that it prints 4 blank stickers after each correct label, I have tried to adjust the label sizes to be less than the actual sticker size but still it keeps printing 4 blank stickers between prints.

this is is how it prints it.

[image]

This is my html code.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Printing Order</title>
    <style>
    *{box-sizing:border-box;}
    @media print {
        .pagebreak { page-break-after: always; } /* page-break-after works, as well */
         html, body {
                height: 99%;    
            }
    }
    body{
        width:100%;
        padding:0;
        font-size:11px;
        line-height:20px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    .label{
        padding:0;
        height:80px;
        width:98%;
        margin:0 auto;
        page-break-after: always;

    }
    .lc{display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center; flex-direction: column;}
    .off{color:#636060;}
    .fss{font-size:10px;}
    .flr{float:right;}
    .tc{text-align:center;}
    .fs14{font-size:14px; font-weight:800;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="label"><div style="padding:10px 15px;">
        <div class="fss off">Le plus vite possibl <span class="flr">04/23/2021 09:15 pm</span></div>
        <b>Somename</b>, 0484000000<br>
        Address NA, NA 6010</div>
    </div>
    <div class="label lc tc fs14">
        <div style="padding:10px 15px;">Veg Cutlets</div>
    </div><div class="pagebreak"></div>
    <div class="label lc tc fs14">
        <div style="padding:10px 15px;">Chapatti</div>
    </div><div class="pagebreak"></div>
    <div class="label lc tc fs14">
        <div style="padding:10px 15px;">Chapatti</div>
    </div><div class="pagebreak"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest specifying your lengths in `mm` rather than `px`. Also, try to limit the amount of white space between tags.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I have done the lengths in mm first it didn't work, This is actually a PHP generated code so there are no white space gaps between the tags at all. I have just formatted it here for the demo purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Printer layouts are more concerned with Printer settings.
An updated version of the driver should be installed in your system.
You can check your HTML page layout on an ordinary printer & test with different sizing.

If this doesn't work you can define your sizing in `"%"` on the HTML page.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, can you explain how do I do it with "%" any example for a 102mm x 24mm sticker?

Comment: Are you asking for the whole size in percentage?
No! I mean you can cover your white space inside the page with the percentage of height in each module.

Comment: The TSC DA210 printer has 102mm x 24mm fixed size and each label is resized according to that followed by a page break break on web page.

Comment: Have you downloaded its driver?
I had the same problem with a printer & tried many things. But ended up with the problem of printer settings.